# How to add an 1x1 ad through tags in Google Ad Manager

Tags: javascript, html, google-ad-manager

I am very experienced in web development but kind of new to Ad Manager and that stuff. So, a client of ours asked us to convert a video to an HTML5 ad. We converted the after effects video to an svg animation successfully. On top of that, we wrote a simple html file with a simple js that starts the animations, adds a close button and so on.

We bundled all the files to a zip and we sent it to several (big) online media sites. So far so good.

Several websites added the HTML5 ad successfully to their Google ad manager and sent us a preview link where the ad plays as expected. The ad is live on these websites now and everything is fine. Now, here comes two questions:

1. there are a couple of websites that need the zip file to be less than 1MB. While this is true due to platform's limitations, how come and the other websites published it without any problems? The zip file is 1,08MB. Is there any work around? Because not matter what I do, I can't make it under 1MB.
2. The most important question is this: one website asked to send the ad through code with tags because they run it through macros. I read almost everything there is out there the past days and I managed to call the ad using an iframe. I am sure that the way I did it is not correct or elegant, but it worked! At least it worked in the platform's preview. When posted on the website is not loading :/ apart from that, they now ask me not to use iframe but script.

I have no idea how to do this :) any idea or direction would be awesome and highly appreciated :)

Thank you all in advance ❤️

Comment: Are you using the default settings to create the zip? If so, you might try adjusting some of the compression settings. Since it's an HTML5 ad you can also try minifying or, if you already minify, adjusting the settings for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regarding the size of the zip, I've already minified all the included files and also I've used "better compression" with winrar (although I am not sure it makes any difference).

Comment: do you, by any chance, have a Google Ad Manager account ? Or any other adserver account ? I guess they are asking you to deliver a "third party" creative (javascript redirects).

Comment: @rabsom I do have a Google Ad Manager account. I am using it only for testing and playing reasons. So, if this is what they actually ask for. How am I doing it? I upload the creative in my Ad Manager account and then?